# How to use python to connect to linux port

Tags: python, linux, curl

I am now facing the problem with using python to connect to one port which requires username/password.

The web URL is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9200/_plugin/head/, which is for elasticsearch. I think the administrator has set firewall for the port, when I want to log in with web browser, the web browser will require username/password, if wrong, the web page will show "authentication failed". And when I use another Linux server to use query port directly with command like

`curl -XPOST 'xx.xx.xxx.x:9200/iqas_week/_search?pretty=true' -d ...`

The server will also return "Authentication Required"

My plan is to use python to connect to this port and write some query for elasticsearch just like the code above. Now with encrypted port, how can I connect to that port in python? I have  tried with paramiko, it works for port 22 but not for port 9200, is there any other way to connect to this port using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use urllib2 to connect to the elasticsearch listener as I believe it's just an HTTP(s?) listener.  Why not use the elasticsearch though?

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Comment: Will try that latter in the company server, it seems that this will work with authentication. Thanks and will feed back afterwords.

Comment: Good luck with it.

Comment: It worked! The authentication method in your link worked with the authentication, thanks for your help

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it!